# Deleted Contribute permission level and want it back

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, onedrive-for-business, contribute

I have been playing around with permissions on my Office365 subscription. I have accidentally deleted the Contribute permission level and now I am unable to restore or create another one with all the attributes of Contribute permission level.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a permission level on the top level site of a site collection.  You can find this by going to `Site Settings -> Site Permissions -> Permission Levels (in Permissions tab) -> Add a Permission Level`.  From here you can recreate a Contribute group.

Here's an article that has the default permissions for each level as well if you want to exactly recreate the Contribute group.

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Permission-levels-and-permissions-49d456eb-d3c8-4402-86b1-deb911224afb

Comment: Thanks, just did that. Now, the problem is that Contribute has a RoleTypeKind 3, and when I create a replica of Contribute, it is assigned a RoleTypeKind 0... how can I fix this?

Comment: I'm getting this >>> Guest links aren’t available because StandardEditorRoleDefinitionID is undefined.>>> When I navigate to the tab for making an item public.

Comment: I tried recreating your issue and haven't had the same experience.  Try copying an existing one by clicking on any of them from the Permission Levels page. At the bottom there is a button to copy permission level. Click that and edit it however you'd like.  I don't know if that will fix it but worth trying.

Comment: No luck, this is what I am getting in API call >>>
{
...
...
...
"BasePermissions": {
                    "__metadata": {
                        "type": "SP.BasePermissions"
                    },
                    "High": "432",
                    "Low": "1011028719"
                },
                "Description": "Can add, edit, and delete items in existing lists and document libraries.",
                "Hidden": false,
                "Id": 1073741925,
                "Name": "Contribute",
                "Order": 2147483647,
                "RoleTypeKind": 0
            }

Comment: I created another one with the same permissions and all.. but it isn't assigned RoleTypeKind 3...